# Prevent pandas read_table from dropping tab characters

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, let's say I have the following string that I want to read with read_table:

`A\tB\tC\t\t\tD\t\tE\t\t\t\t\t\t\t`

Where \t are tab characters.  If I use read_table like so:

```
with open('file.dat') as f:
  df = pd.read_table(f, delimiter = '\r\n\')
```

It will read every line in file.dat but it will drop the trailing \t from each line, and from the example line only keep this:

`A\tB\tC\t\t\tD\t\tE`

On the other hand if I just read the line directly from the file like so:

```
line = []
with open('file.dat') as f:
  for l in f:
    line.append(l)
```

I can confirm the \t are there in the file.

Why does this happen and more importantly how can I prevent it?

Comment: Because \t is not the delimiter, \r\n is the newline character for windows.  My expected output is exactly what I have above, a single column, each row containing a line in the file.dat such that df['line'] = 'A\tB\tC\t\t\tD\t\tE\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'  .  I cannot show actual data because it is sensitive but I copied the data and replaced values with A B C D from when I do df['line'][0] (first output) and line[0] (second output) in an ipython notebook

Comment: There was  a problem with pandas read_csv and last comma's causing parsing problems. I guess thats is why the last \t is dropped.

Comment: I'd wager it drops all \char characters following the last actual text - I guess that's not good.  Oh well, I guess I need another method.

Answer (score 0):

The default is:

```
read_table(filepath_or_buffer, sep='\t', delimiter=None,
```

Try changing the separator:

```
pd.read_table(f, delimiter = '\r\n\', sep=',' )
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  isn't delimiter and sep the same argument by a different name? I'll give it a shot when I get a chance just in case.

Comment: This leads me to believe differently `delimiter : str, default None
Alternative argument name for sep.`  from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html   but of course I'll give it a shot in a bit and report back.

Comment: I think the 'delimiter' part is working fine.  Lines are getting delimited correctly.  It's just that all the \t characters following the last text character are getting stripped from each of the correctly-delimited lines - I'm currently in the process of trying to build a performant solution to get the data in a dataframe but using the python csv reader which parses the text correctly.

Comment: another idea is columns plus one -- I dont think the delimiter is working properly since last "/t" is being dropped. In fact, all the trailing /t are dropped.  So, you need to tell pd that there is one more column. On my sys the /t were processes as tabs...

Comment: but why would that be due to the delimiter?  \t is not the delimiter it's just a character in a string.

so like 'some\ttext\t\t\t\t\r\n some\tother\text\t\t\t\r\n' becomes 'some\ttext', 'some\tother\text' so it delimits correctly but just dropping the \t

Comment: The point is read_table is consuming the last /t as a tab and likely represent  the /t as a tab.

Comment: Looks like adding quoting = 3 (same as cvs.QUOTE_NONE) solves this problem.  I don't understand why since the beginning lines in the datafile don't have stray quotes (i can't check them all manually since there are 10 million) and yet are themselves affected, but I'll take it